# PHP Downloaded File 0 kb

Tags: php, download, zip

I have a script that need to download a existing .zip file from the same folder where it is located. But, no matter what I do, the download size is always 0 kb, and an alert is fired "Invalid file."

I can open the .zip in the Windows 7 without any problems, the **filesize** returns the correct value, the **is_readable** returns true. I have full privileges at the server where the code is, and it *works* at my local machine.

The following os my code.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");    
$numCatalog = "19482";
$zip_file_name = $numCatalog.'.zip';

if (!file_exists($zip_file_name)) {
    echo "File don't exist!";
    exit;
} elseif (!is_readable($zip_file_name)) {   
    echo "Can't read file!";
    exit;       
} elseif (filesize($zip_file_name) == 0) {
    echo "Invalid file!";
    exit;   
} else {
    ob_get_clean();
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Connection: keep-alive");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($zip_file_name)."\"");
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zip_file_name));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_flush(); flush();
    readfile($zip_file_name);
    exit;
}
?>
```

I've tried many types of **header**, using **fopen**, using **
echo self::url_get_contents**, nothing really works. The .zip is over 700 Mb, and no *php.ini* changes made any difference...

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? IE used to (maybe still does) had a moronic habit of not allowing downloads if you set no-cache headers on the url. It stuffed EVERYTHING through the cache system, so if you downloaded a non-cache file, IE would suck down the bytes and auto-nuke them from the cache, leaving nothing avaialble when it came time to copy the downloaded bytes to the download folder.

Comment: It fails in IE, FF and Chrome...

Comment: Is the Invalid file error from your echo statement testing the filesize?

Comment: Is the message that the browser give me.

Comment: error reporting on? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: No error at all. The file is just "empty" (0 kb), but if I echo the **filesize**, it shows *769155577*, the exact size of the zip.

Comment: Ok, made some tests. Looks like I can ONLY read files with less that 128MB, but using **ini_set("memory_limit","900M")** doesn't work!

In the *php.ini*, I'm using *memory_limit = 900M*.